# Do a Function, Delay and Refresh Page Afterwards

Tags: php

Sorry if it's a dumb question. Just started PHP learning a week ago

I'm making a very simple password system with one right answer. Goal: You type in an incorrect password, and it displays "Incorrect Password" for 2 seconds, and then refreshes the page to avoid Confirm Form Re-submission.

```
echo '<br> Incorrect Password!';
sleep(2);
echo '<style>body{display:none;}</style>'; 
echo '<script>window.location.href = "protecttext.php";</script>'; 
exit;
```

this is what i have right now, but it completely ignores the 'incorrect password' and just refreshes the page 2 seconds later. Is there any way i can achieve my goal without using other languages?

Comment: You can do it with an XMLHttpRequest (JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (but I wouldn't use it for serious stuff...):

```
<?php

echo <<<EOL

<br> Incorrect Password!
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location.href = 'protecttext.php';
}, 2000);
</script>
EOL;

exit;
```

`sleep` will block the page for 2 seconds on server-side -> so it will not work as intended for the client.

Use Javascript `setTimeout` instead.